# Get email ID of user in SPServices

Tags: sharepoint, spservices

I am using SPServices (GetListItems method) to fetch some information from a sharepoint list. The list contains a "People or Group" type field which returns a numeric id and name(Display name) of the user separated by semi-colon like this "43#;John Doe".
I need the email addresses of all the users in this field (in all the rows returned). Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paul you rock :)

From Paul's last comment I got the required thing. Its perfect. :)

Only thing you need is to add the following to the call

```
CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><ExpandUserField>True</ExpandUserField></QueryOptions>",
```

SO my example call becomes this

```
$().SPServices({ operation: "GetListItems", async: false, listName: "Assignees", webURL: "https://col.wow.telenor.com/sites/go/",
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True'/>",
            CAMLQuery: "",
            CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><ExpandUserField>True</ExpandUserField></QueryOptions>",
            completefunc: function (xData,Status) {

                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {

                    try {
                    //ows_Name1 is a field of type "People or Group" the after adding CAMLQueryOptions this field returns all the fields
                    // propeties of user i.e. Displayname,ID,email id, domain login, sip ID etc all separate by #
                        var title = $(this).attr("ows_Name1"); 
                    // Splitting the resultant string with # give you string array of all the properties. In my case email ID is at 
                    // index 3.
                        var userEmail = userText.split('#')[3];
                    // Below line is added to remove the trailing "," from email id
                        userEmail = userEmail.substring(0,userEmail.indexOf(','));

                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        alert('Exception: ' + e.message);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Sorry Paul I have to unmark you answer and make this one answer :)

Comment: Excellent. This helped me get the user's email, profile picture, and so much more. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

@Mujaba ,

I have done this before by taking the User Name and doing a search for it using the People service and the SearchPrincipals method... Here is an example:

```
var userEmail = '';
var userId    = '43';
$().SPServices({
    operation:      "SearchPrincipals",
    searchText:     "John Doe",
    async:          true,
    completefunc:   function(xData, status){
        $(xData.responseXML).find("PrincipalInfo")
            .each(function(){
                var thisUser = $(this);
                if ($.trim(thisUser.find("UserInfoID").text()) == userId) {
                    userEmail = $.trim(thisUser.find("Email").text());

                    alert("User's email: " + userEmail);

                    return false;
                }
            });
    }
});
```

Paul.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the response, this will work but if we have to parse hundreds of users then it will take too long to load. Anyhow I'll try using this. :)

Comment: Ok.  I dont know why I did not think of this initially.  There is also a  CAML opiton that you can give to GetListItems that is suppose to expand the user fielfds on the response.  I have never used it, but is documented in the SPServices page (http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists).  It is:       CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><ExpandUserField>True</ExpandUserField></QueryOptions>"